# Not able to use square of elements of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to square elements of a data frame in Python but getting a weird answer as it do not concern negative sign

This is my dataframe:

```
         Risk_Weight  weighted_sum_sens  
0           45             225000  
1           45           -1800000  
2           45             450000  
3           48             480000  
4           99             495000  
5           10             100000  
6           10            -100000  
7           49             245000  
8           47            -235000



In[29]:vec = (ws.weighted_sum_sens**2)
vec
Out[29]: 
0    -914607552
1    1594658816
2     636537088
3   -1528233984
4     211864128
5    1410065408
6    1410065408
7    -104542144
8    -609574848
Name: weighted_sum_sens, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Edit your question so that we know what part of code causes trouble, what data you expect and what you get. And please do it in proper English.

Comment: This works for me, post raw data, code to re-create your df in order for others to reproduce. Also what is your pandas and numpy version? What does `df.info()` show?

Answer (score 2):

This is overflow error. Your `dtype` for the column is `int32`, which can only hold integers between `-2147483648` to `2147483647` (i.e. `-2**31` to `2**31 - 1`). And, for example, the first value `225000**2 == 50625000000`. Take a look at [this section of the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html).

You can use a bigger `int` type:

```
>>> df**2
   Risk_Weight  weighted_sum_sens
0         2025         -914607552
1         2025         1594658816
2         2025          636537088
3         2304        -1528233984
4         9801          211864128
5          100         1410065408
6          100         1410065408
7         2401         -104542144
8         2209         -609574848
>>> df['weighted_sum_sens'] = df.weighted_sum_sens.astype(np.int64)
>>> df**2
   Risk_Weight  weighted_sum_sens
0         2025        50625000000
1         2025      3240000000000
2         2025       202500000000
3         2304       230400000000
4         9801       245025000000
5          100        10000000000
6          100        10000000000
7         2401        60025000000
8         2209        55225000000
>>>
```